# Extracting particular Images from Video (using openCV etc)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have multiple conference video (.mp4) wherein the speakers are presenting a slide show and slides are changing randomly (depending on how much speaker wants to comment on it).
I want to extract only the slides from the video.

EDIT: Able to extract the slides, now there are lot of redundant frames being captured, example in the image. How to avoid them?

[image]

```
# Importing all necessary libraries
import cv2
import os

# Read the video from specified path
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\zoomrx\\Desktop\\Video\\1.mp4")

try:
    
    # creating a folder named data
    if not os.path.exists('data_org'):
        os.makedirs('data_org')

# if not created then raise error
except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory of data')

# frame
currentframe = 0

while(True):
    
    # reading from frame
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    roi = frame[166:959,24:1433]

    if ret:
        # if video is still left continue creating images
        
        name = './data/frame' + str(currentframe) + '.jpg'
        print ('Creating...' + name)

        # writing the extracted images
        cv2.imwrite(name, roi)

        # increasing counter so that it will
        # show how many frames are created
        currentframe += 1
    else:
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==27:
        break


# Release all space and windows once done
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please share your latest/greatest code and say which aspects are currently causing you problems. Thank you.

Comment: video composition won't change for the core part of the video, right? then just manually define (`cv.selectROI`) the region and use that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added the code, pl have a look. thanks..

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i did that but the folder wherein i am storing the frames is empty when i run the above code. Any help?

Comment: You need to check if any errors occur when you open and when you read from your video. You shouldn't treat your variable `currentframe` as a Numpy array with an ROI then later as a integer frame counter. You need to add a `while` loop around your `cam.read()` and `cv2.imwrite()` or you'll only process a single frame, not the whole video.

Comment: [mre] is required. debugging is expected. please review [ask]

Comment: Cool - that's looking a lot better. Now you need to detect changes. So, you need to skip the current frame if `thisFrame` is the same as the `previousFrame`. If it isn't the same, you need to save it as an image on disk, then set `previousFrame` to the current frame and go around again. And you are finished!

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983848/extracting-frames-from-video-using-select-roi -- *do not* post duplicate questions

Comment: @MarkSetchell there are a lot of instances wherein the frame transitions is also being captured, which is not needed, (attaching a screenshot for better understanding). how to ovecome that?

Comment: Maybe sample your frames less often. Let's assume each slide is on the screen for at least a few seconds, so as a crude first attempt... get your frame rate at the start (e.g. 30fps) and then read and process one frame, then discard the next 59 frames so you only look at the video every 2 seconds and won't detect as many mixed transition scenes. There are more sophisticated methods but this might get you started.

Comment: Would you consider a *much simpler*, non-Python solution?

Comment: @MarkSetchell earlier i used to get the slides manually, so any automated solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is much simpler to do cropping and scene change detection with `ffmpeg`, so I made a test video like this:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=640x480:rate=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
```

That is too big to upload to StackOverflow, so it looks like this as an animated GIF with reduced size, quality and frame rate:

[image]

Then, I crop out the counter and do scene-change detection within the cropped area:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -vf "crop=80:120:500:180, select=gt(scene\,0.001)" -vsync 0  -pix_fmt yuv420p cropped.mov
```

That looks like this, again as a reduced size/quality animated GIF:

[image]

Note that the format of the `crop` filter is:

```
crop=WIDTH:HEIGHT:X-COORDINATE:Y-COORDINATE
```

Then I can do more or less exactly what you want and output PNG images of each slide:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -vf "crop=80:120:500:180, select=gt(scene\,0.001)" -vsync 0 slides-%03d.png
```

Which gives me this:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  455  7 Oct 11:59 slides-001.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  466  7 Oct 11:59 slides-002.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  487  7 Oct 11:59 slides-003.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  434  7 Oct 11:59 slides-004.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  473  7 Oct 11:59 slides-005.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  456  7 Oct 11:59 slides-006.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  459  7 Oct 11:59 slides-007.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  441  7 Oct 11:59 slides-008.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  464  7 Oct 11:59 slides-009.png
```

[image]

If you wanted to only look at one slide per second, to avoid transition frames, you could use:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 ...
```

Additionally, you could increase the 0.001 threshold so the frames need to be more different before a transition is detected.

Comment: Hey Mark, that's fantastic, will definitely give it a try. Thanks a ton! :)